# Python For loop not running each item?

Tags: python, for-loop

If I run this code:

```
a = ['bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob']
b = ['bob']

for item in a:
    if item in b:
        a.remove(item)
```

I expect all the 'bob's to be removed, but there are 3 'bob's left.  I don't understand.  Someone please enlighten me, I think I may be losing my mind.

Comment: Once you remove an element the list gets shorter but the index you are iterating at stays the same. This makes you skip an element. You are better off filtering with a list comp. `a = [i for i in a if i not in b]`

Comment: If you don't care about the order of the list, you can create a new one by `set(a) - set(b)`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, the way it worked in my head is different.  Thanks for the alternative code @Primusa

Comment: For my purposes I don't care about order but I'll keep both ways in mind in the future thanks @tdelaney